# Neither disk booting windows 10 after cloning

Tags: windows-10, boot, clone

Last week I changed the boot (C:) drive for my dad's computer as the old one was too small (only had 10GB of space left).

I tried cloning the disk with Macrium Reflect Free Trial. All seemed to go fine, and the PC was working fine after the clone had finished. Then I turned the PC off and unplugged the old drive and tried booting from the new one. I was greeted by a black screen with a Windows error 0xc000000f and Info: “The boot selection failed because a required drive is inaccessible.” I thought something went wrong with the clone and changed the disk, so i would boot again from the old one. But I received the same error on the old one also.

After then I tired:

- Booting from a USB drive and repairing windows with the Windows Recovery Environment, but I received a message that the “Automatic Startup Repair Couldn’t Repair Your PC”
- I tried to do a Windows install, with the option to keep all the
  files, but the USB boot drive didn’t detect a Windows system.
- I checked the BIOS options and even reset the settings to default. I changed the boot order and disabled fast boot.
- After searching for troubleshoot ideas i then tried the CMD commands for:

  - sfc /scannow
  - BOOTREC /FIXMBR
  - BOOTREC /FIXBOOT
  - BOOTREC /RebuildBcd
  - None of these solutions had any effect

What i did:

- Checked the disks with “diskpart” and there all the disks were visible with correct sizes.
- I have formatted the new disk again inside the Windows Recovery Environment and tried copying directly from CMD with the “xcopy c:\ f:\ /s /e /h /i /c /y” command. The result was the same error.
- After that I formatted the new drive again and did a fresh install of windows on it. This worked and I booted into windows.

After fresh install:

- The computer works normally
- All the data from the old disk is available and I can still access it, so I assume the old disk is not corrupt. And after checking, none of the system or Windows files look like they have been deleted.

My questions:

- Obviously, the PC works on the new drive, but I would still like to have all my data from the old disk also on the new one. I tried manually copying all the folders, but some are restricted or couldn’t be copied. This means none of the programs (like Office, printer drivers, etc.) seem to work when trying to open them from the new disk.

  - So first of all, I am wondering if there is anything else I can do to recover windows on the original (old) drive.
  - Second, I am asking if there is a way to copy all the data, programmes, files and most importantly users to the new drive.